# How to fix "Arguments do not have compatible shapes" when running statsmodels Markov Regression

Tags: python, statsmodels

I am trying to run a Markov regression with time-varying transition probabilities in Python with statsmodels.

So far, I can get an Markov autoregression to run, however, I cannot calculat the Markov regression because the error "Arguments do not have compatible shapes" appears.
Any help is appreaciated!

```
df_source = 'http://econ.korea.ac.kr/~cjkim/MARKOV/data/filardo.prn'
dta_filardo = pd.read_table(df_source, delim_whitespace=True, names=('month', 'ip', 'leading'),nrows=520)
dta_filardo.index = pd.date_range('1948-01-01', '1991-04-01', freq='MS')
dta_filardo['dlip'] = np.log(dta_filardo['ip']).diff()*100
std_ratio = dta_filardo['dlip']['1960-01-01':].std() / dta_filardo['dlip'][:'1959-12-01'].std()
dta_filardo['dlip'][:'1959-12-01'] = dta_filardo['dlip'][:'1959-12-01'] * std_ratio
dta_filardo['dlleading'] = np.log(dta_filardo['leading']).diff()*100
dta_filardo['dmdlleading'] = dta_filardo['dlleading'] - dta_filardo['dlleading'].mean()


mod_filardo = sm.tsa.MarkovAutoregression(
    dta_filardo.ix[2:, 'dlip'], k_regimes=2, order=4, switching_ar=False,
    exog_tvtp=sm.add_constant(dta_filardo.ix[1:-1, 'dmdlleading']))

res_filardo = mod_filardo.fit(search_reps=20)
res_filardo.summary()

########

mod_filardo = sm.tsa.MarkovRegression(
     dta_filardo.ix[2:, 'ip'], k_regimes=2,
     exog_tvtp=sm.add_constant(dta_filardo.ix[1:-1, 'leading']))

res_filardo = mod_filardo.fit(search_reps=20)
res_filardo.summary()
```

The Markov Autoregression works perfectly (up until the ######), and after that I try to run the Markov Regression and receive the error "Arguments do not have compatible shapes". I expected to see a summary like in the autoregression estimation...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for filing this [bug report](https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels/issues/5916). The issue has been [fixed in Github](https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels/pull/5917) and will be in our next release (v0.10.1).

Answer (score 0):

If you trace the stack-trace you will end up in `predict_conditional` method inside `markov_regression.py` and `markov_autoregression.py` in `regime_switching` folder inside `statsmodels.tsa`.

What is weird is that [this line](https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels/blob/59b004546c11b792b69f164aba6331ebb0262c8f/statsmodels/tsa/regime_switching/markov_regression.py#L161) generates a prediction matrix of size **(k_regimes, k_regimes, nobs)** to populate `conditional_likelihoods` tensor.

Markov Regression and AutoRegression both use hamilton filter which performs the following sanity check:

```
k_regimes = len(initial_probabilities)
nobs = conditional_likelihoods.shape[-1]
order = conditional_likelihoods.ndim - 2
dtype = conditional_likelihoods.dtype

# Check for compatible shapes.
incompatible_shapes = (
    regime_transition.shape[-1] not in (1, nobs + order)
    or regime_transition.shape[:2] != (k_regimes, k_regimes)
    or conditional_likelihoods.shape[0] != k_regimes)
```

Since `regime_transition.shape[-1] = nobs = conditional_likelihoods.shape[-1]`, `regime_transition.shape[-1]` cannot be equal to `(nobs+order)`. Therefore, the shapes are not aligned. It kind of seems that this class creates a matrix that cannot get past its superclass' sanity checks only when you provide a exog_tvtp matrix(otherwise regime_transition.shape[-1] = 1).

This is the gist of the issue. I would contact with Chad Fulton(author of this module) for further inquiry.